# Extract string between underscores and dot

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have strings like these:

```
/my/directory/file1_AAA_123_k.txt 
/my/directory/file2_CCC.txt
/my/directory/file2_KK_45.txt
```

So basically, the number of underscores is not fixed. I would like to extract the string between the first underscore and the dot. So the output should be something like this:

```
AAA_123_k
CCC
KK_45
```

I found this solution that works:

```
string='/my/directory/file1_AAA_123_k.txt'
tmp="${string%.*}"
echo $tmp | sed  's/^[^_:]*[_:]//'
```

But I am wondering if there is a more 'elegant' solution (e.g. 1 line code).

Answer (score 4):

With `bash` version >= 3.0 and a regex:

```
[[ "$string" =~ _(.+)\. ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single `sed` command like

```sh
sed -n 's~^.*/[^_/]*_\([^/]*\)\.[^./]*$~\1~p' <<< "$string"
sed -nE 's~^.*/[^_/]*_([^/]*)\.[^./]*$~\1~p' <<< "$string"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/1f8XLQ). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - any text
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[^_/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/` and `_`
- `_` - a `_` char
- `\([^/]*\)` (POSIX BRE) / `([^/]*)` (POSIX ERE, enabled with `E` option) - Group 1: any zero or  more chars other than `/`
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^./]*`  - zero or more chars other than `.` and `/`
- `$` - end of string.

With `-n`, default line output is suppressed and `p` only prints the result of successful substitution.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to process the file names one at a time (eg, within a `while read` loop) you can perform two parameter expansions, eg:

```
$ string='/my/directory/file1_AAA_123_k.txt.2'
$ tmp="${string#*_}"
$ tmp="${tmp%%.*}"
$ echo "${tmp}"
AAA_123_k
```

One idea to parse a list of file names at the same time:

```
$ cat file.list
/my/directory/file1_AAA_123_k.txt.2
/my/directory/file2_CCC.txt
/my/directory/file2_KK_45.txt

$ sed -En 's/[^_]*_([^.]+).*/\1/p' file.list
AAA_123_k
CCC
KK_45
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[^_]*_//;s/\..*//' input_file
AAA_123_k
CCC
KK_45
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, with GNU `grep` you could try following code.

```
grep -oP '.*?_\K([^.]*)' Input_file
```

Explanation: Using GNU `grep`'s `-oP` options here to print exact match and to enable PCRE regex respectively. In main program using regex `.*?_\K([^.]*)` to get value between 1st `_` and first occurrence of `.`. Explanation of regex is as follows:

***Explanation of regex:***

```
.*?_     ##Matching from starting of line to till first occurrence of _ by using lazy match .*?
\K       ##\K will forget all previous matched values by regex to make sure only needed values are printed.
([^.]*)  ##Matching everything till first occurrence of dot as per need.
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler `sed` solution without any capturing group:

```sh
sed -E 's/^[^_]*_|\.[^.]*$//g' file

AAA_123_k
CCC
KK_45
```

Answer (score -3):

This is easy, except that it includes the initial underscore:

```
ls | grep -o "_[^.]*"
```

Comment: Don't parse `ls`, use a glob instead. And quote the grep string.

Comment: Oh actually, OP didn't even mention where the strings are from, so why are you using `ls` in the first place?

Comment: I'm demonstrating a one-line `grep` solution instead of a multi-line `sed` solution.  I don't give a rip where the file names came from, but they clearly are file names.  Given this working example, the OP can stitch this into their pipeline.  Since this is a solution, the downvotes seem inappropriate.